# How to access Angular2 new router querystring

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

How can I access the `querystring` parameters from my component? I have URLs like this:

```
http://myurl.com/myroute?myparam=1
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** The RC.1 `@angular/router` is also deprecated. It's better to stick with `@angular/router-deprecated` (because it has more features and is quite stable) until a new new router is shipped.

---

If you are using router-deprecated then `constructor(private params: RouteParams)` will give you access to all parameters, then you can get specific parameter by `params.get('myparam')`

working of Router in RC is not yet documented, but you can get hold of params in routerOnActivate

```
routerOnActivate(curr: RouteSegment, prev?: RouteSegment, 
             currTree?: RouteTree, prevTree?: RouteTree): void {
  let myparam = curr.getParam("myparam");
}
```