# has no exported member 'RouteParams'

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am using the new angular2 Route (not the deprecated beta-router)

When I try to import the RouteParams like I did in the beta-version, teh IDE tells me that there is no expoted member "RouteParams"

```
import { RouteParams, RouteData } from '@angular/router';
```

There is no documentation on the new router yet, or is there?

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Any hints on how to access the route's parameters?

Comment: there is a duplicate question here:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089662/angular-2-how-to-use-the-new-angular-2-0-0-rc-1-router](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089662/angular-2-how-to-use-the-new-angular-2-0-0-rc-1-router)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RouteParams` don't exist in `@angular/router`

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/#!?apiFilter=routeparams

See also [How to access Angular2 new router querystring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37196334/how-to-access-angular2-new-router-querystring/37198341#37198341)