# How to get the route parameter in Angular 2? (RC - stable - router)

Tags: angular

I'm using the new stable Angular 2 RC version. The documentation for the new router component has not been written yet. I am struggling to simply get a parameter from a navigated to page.

My routes:

```
@Routes([
  {path: '/results', component: ResultListComponent},
  {path: '/result-detail/:id', component: ResultDetailComponent}
])
```

I am navigating to my detail component using:

```
this.router.navigate(['/result-detail', result.primary_id]);
```

finally I don't know how to get the primary_id in the result-detail component, using a 'RouteSegment'?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37196334/how-to-access-angular2-new-router-querystring/37198341#37198341

Comment: Sorry, I should be mentioned that this is the equivalent of RouteParams in the deprecated router. 

EDIT: I may be wrong, there might not be a RouteParams at all. See comments below.

Comment: There are no `RouteParams` in the current router AFAIK.

Comment: I think they've removed it in the latest one, but from this link I thought it was there before: https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/RouteParams-class.html .

Comment: There seems to be an issue with removed classes. The docs are still shown. The example shows `angular2` in imports which means `beta`. RC is `@angular`. If you check https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/#!?apiFilter=routeparams you'll see, it's only listed for `router-deprecated`

Comment: Ok awesome, thank you for clearing that up. I've just read your first comment also. I will use the router-deprecated until a new router is shipped. Thank you Günter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular RC1 Router, you need to have your component implement [*OnActivate*](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/b98c9e74e1ad73dc48eb67471ee91f4a1c01dfb6/modules/%40angular/router/src/interfaces.ts) interface to get the route parameters:

```
import { Router, OnActivate, RouteSegment, RouteTree } from '@angular/router';


Component({
...
})
export class ResultDetailComponent implements OnActivate {
    constructor() { }

    routerOnActivate(curr: RouteSegment, prev?: RouteSegment, currTree?: RouteTree,
                     prevTree?: RouteTree) {
        this.id = curr.getParam('id'),
}
```